# How to make Scala's type system catch this MatchError?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, typeclass, scalaz, static-typing

I've defined an ordering for `Seq[Seq[T]]` such that it's a normal lexicographic ordering except all items (sub-sequences) are reversed first (so that `C,B,A` comes before `A,B,C` but after `A,B,A`):

```
implicit def ReverseListOrdering[T: Ordering] = new Ordering[Seq[T]] {
  override def compare(xs1: Seq[T], xs2: Seq[T]) =
    doCompare(xs1.reverse, xs2.reverse)

  private def doCompare(xs1: Seq[T], xs2: Seq[T]): Int = (xs1, xs2) match {
    case (Nil, Nil) => 0
    case (x :: _, Nil) => 1
    case (Nil, x :: _) => -1
    case (x :: xs, y :: ys) =>
      val a = implicitly[Ordering[T]].compare(x, y)
      if (a != 0) a else doCompare(xs, ys)
  }
}
```

This used to be defined on `List[List[T]]` at first but I later realized I want it for all `Seq[Seq[T]]`; this is why I initially left in the `Nil`s in the pattern matching block, while failing to realize `Nil` never matches e.g. an empty `Array`.

Later I tried to run this block of code:

```
// the Seq[String] declarations are needed; otherwise sample` will be Array[Object] for some reason
val sample = List(
  List("Estonia"): Seq[String],
  Array("Tallinn", "Estonia"): Seq[String],
  List("Tallinn", "Harju", "Estonia"): Seq[String])

println(sample.sorted)
```

This compiles just fine but results in the following error at runtime:

```
scala.MatchError: (WrappedArray(Estonia, Tallinn),List(Estonia)) (of class scala.Tuple2)
```

— while I understand the cause of the error perfectly well, what I fail to understand (or at least accept) is, if the `Ordering` is successfully defined on all `Seq[Seq[T]]`, yet a superficially valid but obviously incompatible (in terms of how `doCompare` is defined) `Seq[Seq[T]]` (i.e. `Array[List[String] | Array[String]]`) attempt to use that ordering results in no static type errors or even warnings whatsoever.

Is this caused by the fact that the pattern matching code is not statically verified to cover all possible "instances" of `Seq[Seq[T]]` and that it only handles the `List` case? If yes, what are the currently available workarounds to achieving type safety in such cases? Is [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) something to be looked at yet again for a decent solution?

`P.S.` I'm aware I could easily do away with a solution that works for all `Seq[Seq[T]]` by not using pattern matching and resorting to `head` and `tail` with an if-else block (or `case` statements if guards, which is only superficially nicer), but I'm keen to learn how to make the most of out Scala's type capabilities (AFAIK F# and Haskell catch these errors for breakfast); not to mention pattern matching is by far more elegant and readable.

Comment: ArrayBuffer is Seq but it is not List. Use Seq.empty instead of Nil, and `+:` instead of `::`

Comment: You are absolutely right, and I actually tried the Seq.empty bit but didn't realize +: was the way to go — however, while I'm definitely grateful for you pointing this out, the gist of my question was about how to make Scala catch this sort of errors in general.

Comment: In general you have to set all possible cases. So you can always add at end: `case (x,y) => sys.error(s"Match error: ($x, $y)")`

Comment: Scala already produces a `MatchError` with the EXACT same error message automtically.

Answer (score 2):

This might be closer:

```
scala> def cmp[A, B[_] <: Seq[_]](xs: B[A], ys: B[A]) = (xs, ys) match { case (Nil, Nil) => true }
<console>:7: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
 required: B[?A1] where type ?A1 (this is a GADT skolem)
       def cmp[A, B[_] <: Seq[_]](xs: B[A], ys: B[A]) = (xs, ys) match { case (Nil, Nil) => true }
                                                                           ^
```

There is a known syndrome when the type parameter is on the class instead of the method.

It has surfaced on the ML recently. [Here.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/M9DK5AQCoeA)

Comparing to:

```
scala> (null: Seq[_]) match { case _: Nil.type => true }
scala.MatchError: null
  ... 33 elided

scala> (null: List[_]) match { case _: Nil.type => true }
<console>:8: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: List(_)
              (null: List[_]) match { case _: Nil.type => true }
                   ^
scala.MatchError: null
  ... 33 elided

scala> (null: List[_]) match { case Nil => true }
<console>:8: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: List(_)
              (null: List[_]) match { case Nil => true }
                   ^
scala.MatchError: null
  ... 33 elided
```

Sorry to be lazy, but off to bed.

Comment: Am I right that according to this, exhaustion checks cannot be relied on when using type classes because type classes rely on objects/classes as opposed to methods?

Comment: Try `def cmp[A, B[_] <: Seq[_]](xs: B[A], ys: B[A]) = (xs, ys) match { case (Seq(), Seq()) => true }` Nil is not the same as Seq() for pattern matching

Comment: @ajozwik The point of the question is to elicit a compile time error. See OP's replies to you.

Comment: @ErikAllik Looks like it will respect sealed traits, so it knows Nil doesn't exhaust List at the bottom. At the top, the GADT skolem thing happens because it doesn't have to worry about subclassing changing the type param (I assume). I didn't have time to explore why that doesn't always help.

Answer (score 1):

Scala compiler produces non-exhaustive match warnings only for `sealed` types, which `Seq` isn't. AFAIK, there is no way to  force it to check, like there is for tail recursion.

> (AFAIK F# and Haskell catch these errors for breakfast)

Haskell doesn't have an equivalent to `Seq`; the code you used to have with `List` is the one which is equivalent to Haskell (modulo laziness), and Scala *does* catch the error in this case. I don't know F# well, but looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx it seems that pattern matching a general `IEnumerable<T>` isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

Use code:

```scala
    implicit def ReverseListOrdering[T: Ordering] = new Ordering[Seq[T]] {
            override def compare(xs1: Seq[T], xs2: Seq[T]) =
            doCompare(xs1.reverse, xs2.reverse)

    private def doCompare(xs1: Seq[T], xs2: Seq[T]): Int = (xs1, xs2) match {
            case (Seq(), Seq()) => 0
            case (x +: _, Seq()) => 1
            case (Seq(), x +: _) => -1
            case (x +: xs, y +: ys) =>
            val a = implicitly[Ordering[T]].compare(x, y)
            if (a != 0) a else doCompare(xs, ys)
            }
   }
```

As I mention is comment Nil is not the same type as Seq(). For example WrappedArray is not a List. And when you use `x :: xs` - it is matched as List. `Array("Tallinn", "Estonia")` is converted to WrappedArray. Always use `+:` in pattern matching when you use Seq

Comment: ...as I've pointed out in a comment just seconds ago: this does *not* answer the question, albeit it *does* offer a pretty good workaround to the specific example. :) also, for the record: my question *already* admits that I'm aware that `Nil` does not match `Array()`.

Comment: Array() is converted to WrappedArray() by implicit conversion. `scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.empty == Seq()`

Comment: @EricAllik I dont see why you dont just accept this solution, i.e. using `Seq()`  or `Seq.empty`, `Nil` is for Lists thats why your having problems

Comment: @samthebest: how does this answer even address the question other than offering a workaround to just the specific example that was used to demonstrate a more general problem; a workaround the existence of which I was already aware of? to remind you: the question is about "how to make the type system do more work here" *not* how to arrive at a working implementation.